# pywallet: Which is the private key of child wallet?

Tags: python, django

Using [pywallet](https://github.com/ranaroussi/pywallet), I have developed ethereum wallet under following code.

```
  seed = wallet.generate_mnemonic()
  wallet_info = wallet.create_wallet(network=network, seed=seed, children=0)
```

In this case wallet info is as follow.

```
 {
  "coin": "BTC",
  "seed": "guess tiny intact poet process segment pelican bright assume avocado view lazy",
  "address": "1HwPm2tcdakwkTTWU286crWQqTnbEkD7av",
  "xprivate_key": "xprv9s21ZrQH143K2Dizn667UCo9oYPdTPSMWq7D5t929aXf1kfnmW79CryavzBxqbWfrYzw8jbyTKvsiuFNwr1JL2qfrUy2Kbwq4WbBPfxYGbg",
  "xpublic_key": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcEhoTt7d7qLjtMaE7rrACt42otGYdhv4dtYzwK3RPkfJ4nEjpFQDdT8JjT3VwQ3ZKjJaeuEdpWmyw16sY9SsoY68PoXaJvfU",
  "wif": "L1EnVJviG6jR2oovFbfxZoMp1JknTACKLzsTKqDNUwATCWpY1Fp4",
  "children": []
}
```

Here exists private key.
But when I create a child wallet, there has no private key.
If so, which private key can I use to send transaction from child wallet?
Help!!!!!

```
{
  wallet_path: m/12341234/1,
  bip32_path: m/44'/60'/0'/12341234/1,
  address: MYADDRESS
}
```

Comment: can you also show us how you _create a child wallet_ and what info it shows?

Comment: Of course. I'll update my question. :)